# RavenDB ignoring environment variables in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ravendb

I am trying to setup a cluster of 3 RavenDB instances using docker-compose and I am having problems with the RavenDB server not picking up the values in the `RAVEN_` environment variables.

At first, I was running a single instance, using this docker-compose file:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  ravendb:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "38888:38888"
    volumes:
      - ../data:/opt/RavenDB/Server/RavenData
```

With a simple Dockerfile that used the latest raven image and simply copied a settings.json file into the container.

```
FROM ravendb/ravendb

COPY settings.json /opt/RavenDB/Server/settings.json
```

```json
{
    "License.Eula.Accepted": true,
    "License": {/*License here*/},
    "Setup.Mode": "Unsecured",
    "Security.UnsecuredAccessAllowed": "PublicNetwork",
    "ServerUrl": "http://0.0.0.0:8080",
    "ServerUrl.Tcp": "tcp://0.0.0.0:38888"
}
```

Now that I am trying to setup 3 instances, I wanted to avoid this way of creating the containers, since I would have to have different Dockerfiles and a settings.json file for each one.
Therefore, I thought of using a single docker-compose file that creates three containers and configures each one with [enviroment variables](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.0/csharp/server/configuration/configuration-options#environment-variables).
I started with a single instance, to see if any problems would arise:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  raven1:
    container_name: raven1
    image: ravendb/ravendb
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "38888:38888"
    environment:
      - RAVEN_Security_UnsecuredAccessAllowed=PublicNetwork
      - RAVEN_Setup_Mode=Unsecured
      - RAVEN_License_Eula_Accepted=true
      - "RAVEN_ServerUrl=http://0.0.0.0:8080"
      - "RAVEN_ServerUrl_Tcp=tcp://0.0.0.0:38888"
    volumes:
      - ../data:/opt/RavenDB/Server/RavenData
```

And arise they did! Despite the environment variables being set correctly, they are not picked up by the server, and the settings.json file is the default one.

```
root@8ad95cc439d4:/opt/RavenDB/Server# env
RAVEN_ARGS=
RAVEN_Security_UnsecuredAccessAllowed=PublicNetwork
RAVEN_AUTO_INSTALL_CA=true
RAVEN_ServerUrl=http://0.0.0.0:8080
RAVEN_SETTINGS=
RAVEN_ServerUrl_Tcp=tcp://0.0.0.0:38888
RAVEN_IN_DOCKER=true
RAVEN_Setup_Mode=Unsecured
RAVEN_License_Eula_Accepted=true
RAVEN_DataDir=RavenData
root@8ad95cc439d4:/opt/RavenDB/Server# cat settings.json
{
    "Security.UnsecuredAccessAllowed": "PrivateNetwork"
}
```

Any idea why this might be happening? I can't seem to find any mention of issues regarding this.

Answer (score 3):

Do I understand correctly you expected the configuration from environment variables to be included in the *settings.json* file in the container?

If that's the case I would like to clarify that passing environment variables does not modify RavenDB's *settings.json* file. Instead RavenDB loads them up directly from the environment.

Configuration options are loaded in the following order of precedence:

- command line arguments
- *settings.json* configuration file
- `RAVEN_` prefixed environment variables

So if you wanted to override the configuration option `Security.UnsecuredAccessAllowed` found in *settings.json* file you would need to either change the file on the container or pass it as a CLI argument `--Security.UnsecuredAccessAllowed PublicNetwork`.

Both cases are supported by RavenDB docker images:

- to clear the default `settings.json` you can pass `RAVEN_SETTINGS={}` environment variable to the container.
- to pass command line arguments to the RavenDB server binary you can use `RAVEN_ARGS` environment variable. E.g. `RAVEN_ARGS=--Security.UnsecuredAccessAllowed PublicNetwork`